# Light doesn’t come on if another one is on

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I’m dealing with an issue as a result of a recent renovation. My bedroom light attached to a ceiling fan doesn’t turn on it the adjacent bathroom light is on.

**Scenario 1 - it works**

- Both switches off
- Turn bedroom switch on, bedroom light turns on
- Turn bathroom switch on, bathroom light turns on, bedroom light stays on

**Scenario 2 - it doesn’t work**

- Both switches off
- Turn bathroom switch on, bathroom light turns on
- Turn bedroom switch on, bedroom light does not turn on, bathroom light stays on
- Turn bathroom light off, bedroom light stays off

Comment: Are these two separate(single pole) switches or something weird like three/four ways switches?  Are both lights on the same breaker or two different breakers?

Comment: On the two switches,  do both switches have the word ON and OFF molded into their handle?  Is either light intended to be controlled by two switches?

Comment: I should have clarified: bathroom switch is a Lutron smart dimmer, bedroom switch is a standard single pole with ON and OFF on it, it is not a three-way. Same circuit